# Google Analytics: How to track goal steps with events?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am looking for a way to setup several goal steps that are **not** URLs.

My funnel should look like:

1. unique visitor
2. interested visitor (visited more than 1 page)
3. registration started user (event fired)
4. registered user <- goal (event fired)

But I can't identify some of those 'steps' by a simple URL.

My approach is now to fire an event with an url like:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'reg', 'regstart', {'page': '/my-new-page#regstart'});
```

and for registration success

```
ga('send', 'event', 'reg', 'regsuccess', {'page': '/my-new-page#regsuccess'});
```

and this is my config:

[image]

I fired the events via console to see if it works - but nothing shows up in analytics report.

Any ideas why?

**Edit 1**: I edited my whole question because of @Geoff Jackson recommendation to track this special url with an event.

Comment: Yes you could still do that with URL's. Just specify step 2 as a wildcard on the domain.

Comment: And what about step 3? There's on each page the possibility to open a regform.

Comment: Just make the regform append the URL with something when opened and use that in the URL for the step.

Comment: Do you mean something like `#regform`? That's a good idea, but still bad that we've to use workaround instead good solutions - but it's for free... well, not totaly, they get all of our user data.

Comment: It isn't a workaround though - that's how it is supposed to work and what it caters for. You can use [regular expressions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en-GB) as and how is needed in Google Analytics for scenarios such as yours. If you aren't happy with this kind of config in GA, your web developer could always implement something further on your site that would make this process even easier for GA tracking.

Comment: And this still doesn't work if you have something like `facebook connect` - ack - I guess I've to create this funnel manually.

Comment: Not sure what facebook connect has to do with anything, you didn't specify this in your original question.

Comment: But why do they give us dimensions and events but not the chance to use them in goal steps? I should build my tracking so that it fits into my system and not my system so that it works with tracking.

Comment: Okay - when I use something like `#regform` - than I've to send a new pageview hit, correct? But those hits I've to filter out in regular statistic because it's not a common hit.

Comment: You'd only trigger it when the link is clicked not when the page that contains the link is viewed. You might want to raise a new question with more specifics to prevent this comment discussion extending forever.

Comment: Okay - I'll edit my whole question. But I have to send the hit as soon as user sees the page because this link that opens regform is on every page. If I'd send this hit only when someone clicks the link, I'd have almost no visitors ;)

Comment: No, you have to [event track](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) the URL...

Comment: You mean like `ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {'page': '/my-new-page#regform'});` and then regexp for `regform`. [https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events] (universal event tracking)

Comment: I edited now my whole question. Now I'm not sure if you meant this event tracking or just something like `ga('send', 'pageview', '/my-overridden-page?id=1');` - and tbh, that just looks like a workaround because common events are not avaible in goal steps validation.

Answer (score 5):

@Geoff Jackson helped me to write this little how to.

If you have a website with a lot of Ajax in use or just steps/goals that you can not identify via URL you will have to use extra `pageview`-tracking. That is because Google Analytics does not allow custom events or dimensions in their goal steps.

**Example:**
On each page of your website is a button that opens a lightbox with a registration form.
When your visitor registers, there will not be a 'thank you' page. Informations about next step, that he has to check his email account for an activation link, will show up in this lightbox too. Your **goal** is that a visitor activates his account by clicking this link in email that you have sent him.

First we integrate the events for...

... starting registration process. This event will be fired as soon as the lightbox with registration form opens.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/regStart');
```

... next is when he sends the `regform`. Event will be fired as soon as server answers via Ajax that confirmation mail was sent and on screen is an appropriate message.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/regSuccess');
```

... and finally, we setup an event for our goal. That will be fired as soon as he clicked the activation link in the confirmation mail.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/accountActivated');
```

This last step is not necessary if you've a special 'account activated' page. But since there could be many possibilities and you don not want/can not use `regexp`, this might be a good solution.

Now we have to setup this goal at your Google Analytics account like this:
[image: Goal setup at Google Analytics]

I test such scenarios with simple console calls - so if you just want test it - setup your goal and copy paste those GA-events.

[Here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091) you can read more about it at Google docs.